# Is Norepinephrine beta2 adrenomimetic?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, physiology, pharmacology, neurotransmitter

I know that it has alpha1, alpha2 and beta1 effects. 
It has beta2 receptor where epinephrine can effect. 
However, to say that it is beta adrenomimetic, I am not sure. 
That is ligand binding beta2 receptor causes a stimulatory effect.

**Is norepinephrine beta2 adrenomimetic?**

Comment: Masi, did you try pubchem? [Section 14 lists all the biological properties with references](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/norepinephrine#section=DrugBank-Interactions). You can do this with any molecular compound.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Thank you very much for your excellent comment! I had forgotten this database PubChem. It is so useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in [PubChem](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/norepinephrine#section=DrugBank-Interactions), which is linked in the comment by anongoodnurse.

I would not say that

```
Norepinephrine is beta2 adrenomimetic
```

because norepinephrine has many roles such as neurotransmitter. 
I would just say that

```
Norepinephrine is alpha, beta adrenoagonist.
```

More pieces of information about it from PubChem:

[image]